# g++ template error Small_size

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++14

I am working on the latest revision of the C++ programming language (think it's 5) and run into a problem with g++ version 5.2.

My code is a variation of Small_size template from chap 24.

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
bool is_small ()
{
  std::cerr << sizeof(N) << std::endl;
  std::cerr << N << std::endl;

  return N <= 255;
}


bool ism (int i_n)
{
  return i_n <= 255;
}


int main ()
{
  std::cout << "hallo welt" << std::endl;

  std::cout << 0 << " " << is_small<0> << std::endl;
  std::cout << 255 << " " <<is_small<255> << std::endl;
  std::cout << -4100000000 << " " << is_small<-4100000000> << std::endl;
  std::cout << 256 << " " << is_small<256> << std::endl;
  std::cout << 256 << " " << ism(256) << std::endl;
  std::cout << 256 << " " << (256 <= 255) << std::endl;
}
```

When I compile it, it's ok. But when I run the thing, it simply seems to be broken.

```
[cpp11@hydra src]$ cat ~/bin/g14
#!/bin/bash
g++-52 -std=c++14 "${1}.C" -L$LIBPATH -o "$1"
[cpp11@hydra src]$ g14 konzept_small
[cpp11@hydra src]$ ./konzept_small 
hallo welt
0 1 
255 1
-4100000000 1
256 1                    //1
256 0
256 0
[cpp11@hydra src]$
```

My problem is that:

1. the result for 256 and higher is wrong. See comment  //1
2. there is no output of the template code on `cerr`

I started with a version without the `cerr`, but got only the wrong template result.

I removed a `constexpr` from the template, but no change.

So I added as last step the `cerr` to see whats wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `is_small<N>`, but just printing out its address. You need to change your code to

```
std::cout << 0 << " " << is_small<0>() << std::endl;
std::cout << 255 << " " <<is_small<255>() << std::endl;
std::cout << -4100000000 << " " << is_small<-4100000000>() << std::endl;
std::cout << 256 << " " << is_small<256>() << std::endl;
```

Note the added `()`. Not sure why you are getting the output you are though, are you sure you are running the same code you posted?

Answer (score 1):

`is_small` is a function you should add the parenthesis : 
change

```
std::cout << 0 << " " << is_small<0> << std::endl;
```

to this

```
std::cout << 0 << " " << is_small<0>() << std::endl;
```

It worked fine for me with this change